# JSON underscore in PropertyName gives NULL value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've got an issue when deserializing a JSON string where the PropertyNames with underscores give a NULL value when converting to .NET objects. It's a strange issue since there are only a few properties with an underscore that returns a value, the rest return `NULL`.

I use RestSharp to query -

```
static RestClient client = new();

public static async Task QueryAuctionRegistrations()
        {
            string am_baseURL_v2 = Settings.Default.AM_BASE_URL;
            string am_q_auction = Settings.Default.AM_Q_AUCTION;
            string am_q_client = Settings.Default.AM_Q_CLIENT;
            string am_p_email = Settings.Default.AM_P_EMAIL;
            string am_auctionID = Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_ID;
            string am_reg = Settings.Default.AM_REGISTRATIONS;
            string am_token = Settings.Default.AM_TOKEN;

            try
            {
                client = new($"{am_baseURL_v2}{am_q_auction}{am_auctionID}/{am_reg}?o=0&n=1000");
                RestRequest request = new();
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", am_token);
                var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT = response.Content;
                CleanJSON(Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException + "\n" + e.HResult, "API error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
```

The `CleanJSON();` method is used to remove query information from the response before deserilizing. This is the response before cleaning -

```
{
    "result_page": [
        {
            "auction_id": "4-6PFFSH",
            "approved_at": null,
            "reviewed_at": null,
            "submitted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2022-07-22T00:35:22.202Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-07-22T00:35:22.202Z",
            "paddle": "1002",
            "account_uuid": "bb78e4b0-8ff4-46c6-88d4-f92c28e25692",
            "max_spendable": null,
            "total_spent": "0.00",
            "max_spendable_limit": null,
            "analytics": {},
            "shipping_method": null,
            "creating_client_id": "4-J5SO",
            "customer_id": "4-KQHHP",
            "total_applied_deposits": "0.00",
            "escrow_transaction_record_id": null,
            "pickup_location": null,
            "request_shipping_quote": false,
            "location_country": null,
            "paid_fields_changed_date": null,
            "paid_fields_last_sync_date": null,
            "paid_is_synced": false,
            "row_id": "4-6PKIDA",
            "card_id": "",
            "card_service": "stripe",
            "either_or": {
                "max_spendable": null,
                "max_quantity": null,
                "groups": []
            },
            "effective_max_spendable": null,
            "is_approved": false,
            "customer": {
                "created": "2020-06-29T11:47:00.047Z",
                "creating_client_id": "4-J5SO",
                "facebook_uid": null,
                "name": "Andrew Els",
                "facebook_email": null,
                "preferred_email": "andrew.taiwan@yahoo.com",
                "login": "andrew.taiwan@yahoo.com",
                "phone_number": "0791896341",
                "tenant_id": "4-J5SH",
                "override_tenant_id": null,
                "preferred_payment_method": null,
                "paddle": null,
                "approved_at": "2020-06-29T11:47:00.045Z",
                "reviewed_at": null,
                "credit_approved": null,
                "given_name": "Andrew",
                "family_name": "Els",
                "textsearch_index_column": "'andrew':1 'el':2",
                "integration_id": null,
                "is_external_record": false,
                "username_alias": null,
                "title": null,
                "fax_number": null,
                "external_account_number": null,
                "preferred_credit_card_id": null,
                "default_auction_max_spendable_limit": null,
                "default_auction_max_spendable": null,
                "last_updated": "2022-07-22T00:35:22.030Z",
                "phone_number_two": null,
                "notes": null,
                "source": null,
                "referrer_host": null,
                "referrer_path": null,
                "do_not_email": false,
                "auto_approve_auction_registrations": false,
                "custom_fields": {},
                "owner_alias": null,
                "opt_in_marketing": false,
                "show_address_summary_in_auction": true,
                "block_auction_registrations": false,
                "phone_number_country": null,
                "phone_number_local_number": null,
                "fax_number_country": null,
                "fax_number_local_number": null,
                "is_deleted": null,
                "date_of_birth": null,
                "nationality": null,
                "requires_auction_registration_document": true,
                "preferred_timezone": null,
                "is_kyc_uploaded": false,
                "is_only_integration_id": false,
                "paid_external_id": null,
                "paid_fields_changed_date": null,
                "paid_fields_last_sync_date": null,
                "paid_is_synced": false,
                "is_login_disabled": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
                "is_customer_delete_requested": null,
                "row_id": "4-KQHHP",
                "company_name": "Teacher",
                "role": "user",
                "created_at": "2020-06-29T11:47:00.048Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-06-30T08:52:10.194Z",
                "customer_id": "4-KQHHP",
                "uuid": "bb78e4b0-8ff4-46c6-88d4-f92c28e25692",
                "shipping_address_id": "4-KTBOL",
                "addresses": [],
                "payment_methods": [],
                "cardcustomers": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "query_info": {
        "page_size": 1,
        "total_num_results": 41,
        "page_start_offset": 0,
        "prev_page": null,
        "base_query": "https://production4-server.auctionmobility.com/v2/admin/auction/4-6PFFSH/registrations",
        "next_page": "https://production4-server.auctionmobility.com/v2/admin/auction/4-6PFFSH/registrations?o=1&n=1"
    }
}
```

The response after the `CleanJson()` method -

```
{
  "auction_id": "4-6GKA1V",
  "approved_at": null,
  "reviewed_at": null,
  "submitted_at": null,
  "created_at": "2022-06-24T09:05:39.329Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-06-24T09:05:39.329Z",
  "paddle": "1001",
  "account_uuid": "767def80-e55f-4326-a4f8-71212813ae3f",
  "max_spendable": null,
  "total_spent": "0.00",
  "max_spendable_limit": null,
  "analytics": {},
  "shipping_method": null,
  "creating_client_id": "4-27304",
  "customer_id": "4-5MJI3G",
  "total_applied_deposits": "0.00",
  "escrow_transaction_record_id": null,
  "pickup_location": null,
  "request_shipping_quote": false,
  "location_country": null,
  "paid_fields_changed_date": null,
  "paid_fields_last_sync_date": null,
  "paid_is_synced": false,
  "row_id": "4-6GU8LL",
  "card_service": "stripe",
  "either_or": {
    "max_spendable": null,
    "max_quantity": null,
    "groups": []
  },
  "effective_max_spendable": null,
  "is_approved": false,
  "customer": {
    "created": "2022-04-05T07:31:17.869Z",
    "creating_client_id": "4-27304",
    "facebook_uid": null,
    "name": "**********",
    "facebook_email": null,
    "preferred_email": "**********",
    "login": "**********",
    "phone_number": "**********",
    "tenant_id": "4-J5SH",
    "override_tenant_id": null,
    "preferred_payment_method": null,
    "paddle": null,
    "approved_at": "2022-04-05T07:31:17.871Z",
    "reviewed_at": null,
    "credit_approved": null,
    "given_name": "WEMVULA HOLDINGS ",
    "family_name": "WEMVULA",
    "textsearch_index_column": "'hold':2 'wemvula':1,3",
    "integration_id": null,
    "is_external_record": false,
    "username_alias": null,
    "title": null,
    "fax_number": null,
    "external_account_number": null,
    "preferred_credit_card_id": null,
    "default_auction_max_spendable_limit": null,
    "default_auction_max_spendable": null,
    "last_updated": "2022-06-24T09:05:38.512Z",
    "phone_number_two": null,
    "notes": null,
    "source": null,
    "referrer_host": null,
    "referrer_path": null,
    "do_not_email": false,
    "auto_approve_auction_registrations": false,
    "custom_fields": {},
    "owner_alias": null,
    "opt_in_marketing": false,
    "show_address_summary_in_auction": true,
    "block_auction_registrations": false,
    "phone_number_country": null,
    "phone_number_local_number": null,
    "fax_number_country": null,
    "fax_number_local_number": null,
    "is_deleted": null,
    "date_of_birth": null,
    "nationality": null,
    "requires_auction_registration_document": true,
    "preferred_timezone": null,
    "is_kyc_uploaded": false,
    "is_only_integration_id": null,
    "paid_external_id": null,
    "paid_fields_changed_date": null,
    "paid_fields_last_sync_date": null,
    "paid_is_synced": false,
    "is_login_disabled": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "is_customer_delete_requested": null,
    "row_id": "4-5MJI3G",
    "role": "user",
    "created_at": "2022-04-05T07:31:17.875Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-05T08:21:52.444Z",
    "customer_id": "4-5MJI3G",
    "uuid": "767def80-e55f-4326-a4f8-71212813ae3f",
    "shipping_address_id": "4-5MJSHW",
    "addresses": [],
    "payment_methods": [],
    "cardcustomers": []
  }
}
```

The `CleanJSON()` method -

```
private static void CleanJSON(string jsonString)
{
    try
    {
          var string1 = ReverseString(jsonString);
          var output1 = string1.Remove(0, 217);
          var string2 = ReverseString(output1);
          var output2 = string2.Remove(0, 17);
          Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT = output2;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          var string1 = ReverseString(jsonString);
          var output1 = string1.Remove(0, 218);
          var string2 = ReverseString(output1);
          var output2 = string2.Remove(0, 17);
          Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT = output2;
      }
}
```

My `Customer` object, I've left out properties I don't care about -

```
[JsonProperty("customer_id")]
public string CustomerID { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("company_name")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("given_name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("family_name")]
public string Surname { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("paddle")]
public object Paddle { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("preferred_email")]
public string PreferredEmail { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("phone_number")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

This is the deserializing method -

```
customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(jsonString, Converter.Settings);
```

This is my converter settings -

```
public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new()
{
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
    StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.Default,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
};
```

The request returns the correct data, however when deseriliazing the data the properties with underscores return a `NULL` value. Only a few properties, including "customer_id", returns a value, see screenshot.

[image: Retunred values 1] [image: Returned values 2]

What am I doing wrong? What can I do differently?

For reference I am using the latest Newtonsoft.json library from NuGet.

Comment: How is the class declared? Can it be that in C# "auction_id" is written as "AuctionId"? Which JSON serializer do you use? System.Text.Json or NewtonSoft.Json?

Comment: Maybe you didn't define the correct json name? If it doesn't find a matching one it would be null. You are not showing us your definition and a sample value that you expect to see result.

Comment: How do you access properties? Do you deserialize to a specific data class or just to a general container of your JSON framework?

Comment: You need to actually show your deserialization logic. If the JSON you have pasted here is the _string_ content after `CleanJSON` then serialization hasn't even occurred yet. Please also include the raw json payload response from the server.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I have added the deserializing logic and JSON payload from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as you have demonstrated here, if your objects after deserialization contain mostly or all `null` values even though the data is there in the JSON string input, then this indicates you may have deserialized into the wrong type.

The server response contains a paged resultset of `Registration`, not `Customer`. But your query has a page size of 1, so the array of results only ever contains a single result. This is the basic structure of the server response:

```
{
    result_page: [
        {
            customer: {}
        }
    ],
    query_info: {
        prev_page: {}
    }
}
```

Your `CleanJSON()` method is reducing this to a single `result_page` object that has a nested `customer` object, but you are trying to deserialize this single object into a `List<Customer>`, which it clearly is not.

I would recommend you drop the `CleanJSON()` process all together, it is using specific character lengths which is a volatile mechanism when we are dealing with highly structured interfaces. For instance, there are 41 results available, if the number of results grows past 99, then the character count would need to be adjusted, because the `total_num_results` property would now have a *3 character value* instead of 2. Also if you were to query the 10th or any higher paged result, then again the character counts would be out due to the `page_start_offset` value using more than a single character, the `next_page` value would also increase in length.

A better solution is to create a model that matches the expected input structure so that we can deserialize the raw response without trying to manually manipulate it as a string. (especially so we can avoid *"magic"* string manipulation, or rather manipulation using *"magic"* numbers.)

> There is no *"magic"* of course in C#, but hardcoding literal or constant values in your code might as well be magic unless you are heavily documenting the source of  these values as well as justification and an explanation of how to verify the values.

Start off by creating this *minimal* model:

```
namespace SerializationModels
{
    public class PagedQueryResponse<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty("result_page")]
        public IList<T> Results { get;set; }
        //[JsonProperty("query_info")]
        //public PagedQueryResponseInfo QueryInfo { get;set; }
    }
    public class RegistrationResult
    {
        public Customer Customer { get;set; }
        // todo: include any other properties that you might want to retrieve from the response.
    }
}
```

Then you **MUST** remove the `CleanJSON()` method from the request logic:

```
try
{
    client = new($"{am_baseURL_v2}{am_q_auction}{am_auctionID}/{am_reg}?o=0&n=1000");
    RestRequest request = new();
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", am_token);
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT = response.Content;
    //CleanJSON(Settings.Default.AM_AUCTION_RESULT);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException + "\n" + e.HResult, "API error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Finally, your deserialization logic is now this:

```
var registrationsResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SerializationModels.PagedQueryResponse<RegistrationResult>>(jsonString, Converter.Settings);
customers = registrationsResponse.Results.Select(r => r.Customer).ToList();
```

Use this Fiddle to verify and experiment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yM5t0G

Comment: Thank you so much @ChrisSchaller. This worked perfectly and I'm able to retrieve the correct information. +1